# Access Use Query in Report

Tags: ms-access, report

Good day.

I have an inventory application.  When an item is moved into production a ticket is required to be printed with a customer name and the product name.  I created the ticket as a report.  I used the following query as the Record Source in the report and it works exactly as I want.

```
    SELECT [PkgSize] & " " & [PkgUnit] AS Pkg, tblProducts.ProductID, tblProducts.ProductPrintName, 
        tblProducts.Grade, tblCustomers.CompanyName, tblOrderDetails.ODEPriority 
    FROM tblCustomers INNER JOIN (tblOrders INNER JOIN (tblProducts INNER JOIN tblOrderDetails 
        ON tblProducts.ProductID = tblOrderDetails.ODEProductFK) 
        ON tblOrders.ORDOrderID = tblOrderDetails.ODEOrderID) 
        ON tblCustomers.ID = tblOrders.ORDCustomerID 
    WHERE (((tblProducts.ProductID)=[Forms]![frmInventoryTransfers]![cboTransferProductID]) 
         AND ((tblOrderDetails.ODEPriority)=1) 
         AND (([tblOrderDetails]![ODEQtyOrdered]-[tblOrderDetails]![ODEQtyProduced])>"0"));
```

The report is opened with the following:

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptProductPaperLabelTCTRlogo", acViewPreview
```

What I want to do is to move the query into my procedure because I need to change values of some items.  For example, I will need to change the ODEPriority to a different number, such as 2 or 3 i.e. change it to a variable.  This will trigger the ORDCustomerID to change but not the ProductID.

I have created a string from the query and tried

```
DoCmd.OpenReport "rptProductPaperLabelTCTRlogo", acViewPreview, , , , Qstring
```

but I get #Name? in all the text boxes. (I first removed the query from the record source in the report.)

I have tried to use a querydef but can't seem to get the syntax right.

Can someone help me with how to move the query into a procedure to make the report dynamic.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OpenArgs` parameter is simply passed to the report. It isn't automatically used for anything, but available in the Report event procedures.

So in `Report_Open()`, you can do:

```
Me.RecordSource = Me.OpenArgs
```

and it should work.

Side note: in the last line, it should be `>0` instead of `>"0"`

Comment: Thanks Andre.  In the string I did change it to >0 but it seems to work in the query as >"0".  I will change it there as well.  Otherwise, your suggestion worked perfectly.  Thank you VERY much.  I couldn't find that answer anywhere.

Comment: @LesProgrammer: Yes, Access is quite lenient with these things, and often auto-converts numbers to strings and vice-versa as needed. But still, you calculate a number (a difference), so you should compare it with a number. :)